# Get data from subcollection

Tags: firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

When I try get data from sub collection in firestore through this code 
You get a problem and this message appears:

> Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but AppliedJobFromEmployees has 1

```
fun getData(onComplete: (MutableList<saveApplaiedEmployeeModel>) -> Unit): ListenerRegistration {
        val id = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser!!.uid
        val doc = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("AppliedJobFromEmployees/ $employerId/applicants/ $id/EmployeeApplicants")
        return doc.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, _ ->
            onComplete(querySnapshot!!.toObjects(saveApplaiedEmployeeModel::class.java))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that `employerId` or `id` are not `null`?

Comment: Please update the question with the exact values of all the variables here.  Also remove the space before $employerId, unless that's what you intended to include.